# Vector space spanned by a non finite family of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a family of vector $A=(a_i)_{i \in [|1:n|]}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$.

We find that $Vect(A)=\{ \sum_{i \in [|1:n|]}\lambda_i ~ a_i, \lambda_i \in \mathbb{K} \}$
($Vect(A)$ is defined as the smallest vector space containing $A$).

My question is :

In my book they limit the definition to a **finite** family. Why ? For me we could have a non finite family. Also we could imagine that the family is uncountable.

And by doing so we could define the smallest vector space containing any set $A$ included in $E$ (not necesseraly a finite and countable family of vectors) by writing : $Vect(A)=\{ \sum_{i \in B}\lambda_i a_i, \lambda_i \in \mathbb{K} \}$

Am I right ?

Comment: In general an infinite sum $\sum_i \lambda_i a_i$ won't make sense in a general vector space.

Comment: Why it won't make sense ? If I take $Vect([-1:1])$ I could imagine to define it as $\sum_i \lambda_i a_i$ where $a_i$ can be any family of numbers between $-1$ and $1$ for example ?

Comment: Consider $V = \mathbb R$ and $a_i = i$ for $i\in(0,1)$. Obviously $\sum_i a_i$ isn't well-defined or an element in $V$.

Comment: Ah yeah there is a problem of convergence in fact. So what I say could be true with the addition of convergence condition of the sum in a sense.

Comment: There is no concept of convergence in a vector space. In a Banach space on other hand, in general the minimal vector space containing $S$ and the space $\{ \sum_{s\in S} a_s s\mid a\in \mathbb R^S \}$ (only considering converging series) are not necessarily the same, if $S$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define the span ("Vect") of an infinite family of vectors. When doing so, it is important to remember that only finite linear combinations of these are allowed.

To see how this works, consider $V$ to be the space of sequences of real numbers, and let $A$ be $\lbrace e_i | i \in \mathbb N \rbrace$, where $e_i$ is the sequence with a 1 in the $i$th spot, and 0 everywhere else.

In this scenario, by analogy to $\mathbb R^n$, you might think that the span ("Vect") of $A$ is the entire space $V$. However, this is not the case. It is in fact the set of all sequences which have a 0 in all but finitely many places. This set does contain the zero vector and adding any two vectors in this set will produce another vector in this set. This, and not the entire space $V$, is the smallest subspace which contains $A$.